# Paypal payment through database

Tags: php, paypal, migration

Good day people!

I have this question: Im making a webshop which currently takes all the items out of the database and shows them with this code:

```
foreach($result as $row) { 
    print "<div id='item'>";
    echo "Product ID: ".$row['ProductID'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<img src=images/".$row['Image'].">";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Price: ".$row['Price'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Desc: ".$row['Description'];
    echo "<br/>";
    if($_SESSION['username'] == ""){
        echo "Login to buy!"; 
    }else{
        echo "<button name='buy'>Buy item</button>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

It works beautifull, but as you can see i have a button "Buy Item",
Is there like any good tutorial about Paypal migration to the buttons for buying a specific item, because i've been looking on the interwebs and couldnt find a good one, thanks in advance!

Luc

Edit: This is how it looks like:

[image: Webshop database output]

Comment: paypal give you the code to put on your website already ? is that not what you want

Comment: Well, ive found a tutorial, but i dont get how i can make it that it works on a button, or do i have to make a cart first?

Comment: have a look here[Paypal Payment Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/)

Comment: Its not the button i have the buttons already (BUY ITEM) buttons, but how can i pass the Product ID too the form of Paypal, so paypal knows which item it is by ID

Comment: when you set the price etc for the button in paypal it gives you a unique code for a button so it knows which product it is. have a look at the link, it explains shopping carts aswell

Comment: and a quick click from that page gives you [Paypal buttons Guides on Paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/). You have all the information you need.

Comment: I found that link just now :D Thanks billy, i got it to work! :D